# Is Nonnumbered a word?

Tags: meaning, grammar, slang, business-language, north-american-english

Is *nonnumbered* a word? My spell check let it slip by, and I can't find out why. Why is it wrong if it is wrong. Is there a conflict with the use of *non* and *ed* in the same word.

Comment: Could you please supply the sentence where the word ***nonnumbered*** was used? The "error" pointed out by MS might be due to other considerations. Thanks. Your spellchecker is MicroSoft, I presume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=non-numbered%2Cnonnumbered&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20numbered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonnumbered%3B%2Cc0) shows usages of the expression non-numbered/nonnumered meaning

"not numbered".

It is from the common usage of ***[non](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/non)***:

> - used to add the meaning "not" or "the opposite of" to adjectives and nouns:
> - *non-sexist
>     non-racist*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

From [Walking broad](https://books.google.it/books?id=GlV6d6iI7hUC&pg=PA7&dq=%22nonnumbered%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy5eHhwIzRAhXOM1AKHeTaBhUQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22nonnumbered%22&f=false):

> - I love how ***they named all the nonnumbered streets*** in Center City after the trees they tore out to make....

From [Binding and Care in Printed Music](https://books.google.it/books?id=3Mg3LuBi2VYC&pg=PA138&dq=%22nonnumbered%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy5eHhwIzRAhXOM1AKHeTaBhUQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22nonnumbered%22&f=false):

> - Any score of forty-eight pages or fewer (***including nonnumbered pages)*** can be photocopied and pamphlet- bound in-house, regardless of the original binding style. T